# How to get rows (row by row) of multiple tables by the old date

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I'm using **Laravel** ,for example I have 3 `Models` , and I get the data recorded by the current user as follows:

```
    $questions = Auth::user()->questions()->orderBy('created_at','desc')->get()->toArray();
    $answers = Auth::user()->answers()->orderBy('created_at','desc')->get()->toArray();
    $comments = Auth::user()->answerComments()->orderBy('created_at','desc')->get()->toArray();
```

For example, the arrays `$question` & `$answers` &  `$comments` have the timestamp columns (`created_at` and `updated_at`) but do not have the same columns , **How can I create a new array to store the three arrays by the oldest date ?**

I'm doing this to get personal history. (comments , answers , questions).

sorry for my English.

Comment: Question isn't entirely clear to me. Do you perhaps mean you want to add questions, answers and comments together and then sort the complete list by created_at?

Comment: Yes I want to create a single array that contains all data list by created_at

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I didn't understand your question exactly , bu you can only do it using some actions like :

**1-first** : make a `function` for return the min date from array of dates :

```
function minDate($dates){
    $now = date("Y-m-d h:i:s", time()); // the time now
    $oldest = $now;   // the oldest date 
    $row = null;      // oldest row will be returned
    foreach($dates as $date){ 
        $curDate = $date['created_at'];
        if ($curDate < $oldest) {
            $oldest = $curDate;
            $row = $date ; // the old row
        }
    }
    return $row;
}
```

**1-second** : tand after getting those three arrays do :

```
$questions = Auth::user()->questions()->orderBy('created_at','desc')->get()->toArray();
$answers = Auth::user()->answers()->orderBy('created_at','desc')->get()->toArray();
$comments = Auth::user()->answerComments()->orderBy('created_at','desc')->get()->toArray();

$data = [$questions ,$answers ,$comments];
$mixed = []; // this for store all rows (finish result)
$k = 0; // We will work on the first row
while(!empty($data[0]) || !empty($data[1]) || !empty($data[2])){

          $arr = [];
          foreach ($data as $d)
          if(isset($d[$k]['created_at']))
               $arr[] = $d[$k]; // Store the first rows in $arr
          $row = minDate($arr); // $row is the oldest row in all arrays
          $mixed[] = $row;  // $the oldest will be stored in $mixed

          for($i=0;$i<=2;$i++){ // Here is the search for the oldest row
              if(isset($data[$i][$k]) && $data[$i][$k] === $row){
                   array_shift($data[$i]); // remove the oldest row 
              }
          }

}
dd($mixed); // and you got $mixed content all rows of all arrays order by created_at
```

Answer (score 1):

You can combine all the tables using UNION then order the results by the created by field in the outer query
Something like this:

```
SELECT * FROM (
(
  Select question as data , 'question' as type, created_at
  FROM questions_table 
  where ( questions_table.user = [your_user_id])
)
UNION
(
  SELECT answer as data, 'answer' as type, created_at
  FROM answers_table
  where ( answers_table.user = [your_user_id])
)
UNION
(
   SELECT comment as data, 'comment' as type, created_at
   FROM comments_table
   where ( comments_table.user = [your_user_id])
)
) 
ORDER BY created_at DESC
```

This will combine all the data then order by the creation date

Comment: This answer results in a good performance and efficiency. However it's only useful when you don't also need the separate arrays.However it'd be highly likely that joins result in a better performance than union (also avoid wildcards)

Comment: If the purpose is only displaying a history of the actions combined then no need to have separate arrays, only distinguishing between them in each row would be enough.
I thought about the joins but you will have to left join all the 3 tables which will result in table1 * table2 * table3 rows, and sometimes only 1 row having 3 history records instead of 3 rows